# symfony4 profiler cache permission error

Tags: symfony, nginx, composer-php

Using nginx 1.12.2 and php 7.1.12, I've just installed Symfony 4.0.3
I saw that the profiler had to be installed with `composer install profiler --dev` which I did but I came up with the

```
(1/1) RuntimeException

Unable to create the storage directory (/AddressOfSymfonyProject/var/cache/dev/profiler).
```

The expected behaviour is

> In the dev environment, umask() is used in bin/console and public/index.php so that any created files are writable by everyone.

The same user **nginx** is used by php-fpm, nginx and it's the owner of `/AddressOfSymfonyProject/` whose cache folder is set with `777` as permission.

Can anyone explain to me how it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

use ll command and see what are the permissions and user on cache directory. Sometimes permissions look good but the user is root then it doesn't allow directory access to everyone.

Comment: It was one of the first thing I checked it's actually the same user as the user nginx uses, and the folder itself has a permission of 777